# Hypotheses in Morera's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I think of Morera's theorem as saying that if $f$ maps some open subset of $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ and the integral of $f$ along every simple close curve (or maybe piecewise smooth simple closed curve?) in that open subset is $0$, then $f$ is holomorphic on that subset.

Some versions of Morera's theorem weaken the hypothesis to say every curve consisting of the sides of a rectangle with each side parallel to either the real axis or the imaginary axis.  Some use triangles or circles.  A **question** arises: which classes of curves can serve?

The usual simple proof says $f(z)=\frac d {dz} \int_{x_0}^z f(w)\,dw$ where $z_0$ is some base point, and uses the hypothesis to show that the integral does not depend on which path is taken from $z_0$ to $z$.  Then one must use the fact that derivatives of holomorphic functions are holomorphic, a proposition whose proof requires some work.

Thus it may at first appear that one must use some class of curves that can connect any chosen base point to any other point in the domain.  But I think one could make a slight variant of the proof work if one simply assumed $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=0$ whenever $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $<0.0001$ within the domain.

So:

- Which classes of curves will serve?
- Is there some nice simple proof that doesn't use an arbitrary choice of base point and that makes the answer to that first question obvious?

Answer (score 1):

1. You did not state the theorem precisely: a crucial requirement is that $f$ is continuous.
2. Any class of closed curves which contains rectangles or triangles, or smooth curves, or circles will be OK. With circles it is less trivial.

See, for example,

MR0562919
Zalcman, Lawrence
Offbeat integral geometry. 
Amer. Math. Monthly 87 (1980), no. 3, 161–175.

Comment: Interesting.  Your second point is an assertion, and one may surmise that _maybe_ the paper you cite as something more on this.  I wonder if you could make your answer a bit more self-contained by specifically stating which propositions in the paper are relevant and saying what's involved in their proofs? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The paper I mentioned is available for free reading online.

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2321600?sid=21105817687691&uid=3739256&uid=4&uid=2134&uid=3739936&uid=70&uid=2