# Prove Morera's Theorem in circles cases.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that f is continuous on C, and
$$
\oint_C f(z)dz=0
$$
for every circle $C\in \mathbb C$. Prove f is holomorphic in C.

How to deal with this cirlce case?

Comment: @user1952009 We are only given that $f$ is continuous. A priori it may not be differentiable as a real function, in which case it wouldn't be possible to write $f(z)=f(z_0)+(z-z_0)a_1+\overline{(z-z_0)}a_2+o(|z-z_0|)$.

Comment: btw I think this question is covered by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169124/hypotheses-in-moreras-theorem

Comment: @stewbasic yes I was going to say to integrate if $f(z)$ is not real differentiable, but of course once you integrated (and shown it doesn't depend on the path of integration) it becomes obvious $\int f(z) dz$ is holomorphic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Step 1.** Assume first that $f \in C^1$. Then writing $f = u + iv$ for $u, v : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{R}$ shows that for any $z_0 \in \Bbb{C}$ and $r > 0$,

$$ 0 = \oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} f(z) \, dz = \oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} (u \, dx - v \, dy) + i \oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} (u \, dy + v \, dx)$$

and hence the real part and the imaginary part vanish simultaneously. Now by the Green's theorem,

$$ 0 = -\oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} (u \, dx - v \, dy) = \iint_{B_r(z_0)} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right) \, dxdy $$
$$ 0 = \oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} (u \, dy + v \, dx) = \iint_{B_r(z_0)} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) \, dxdy $$

Since this is true for any ball $B_r(z_0)$, dividing both equations by $|B_r(z_0)| = \pi r^2$ and taking $r \to 0$ yields the Cauchy-Riemann equation

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} -= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}. $$

This shows that $f$ is holomorphic.

**Step 2.** Now we only impose the condition that $f$ is continuous. In order to utilize the previous step, let $\varphi : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{R}$ be a compactly supported smooth function such that

$$ \iint_{\Bbb{C}} \varphi(\mathrm{x}) \, d^2\mathrm{x} = 1. $$

Then it is not hard to check that $f_n$ defined by

$$ f_n(z)
= \iint_{\Bbb{C}} f(\mathrm{x})\varphi_n(z-\mathrm{x}) \, d^2\mathrm{x}
= \iint_{\Bbb{C}} f(z-\mathrm{x})\varphi_n(\mathrm{x}) \, d^2\mathrm{x},
\qquad \varphi_n(\mathrm{x}) = n^2 \varphi(n\mathrm{x}) $$

are smooth and the sequence $(f_n)$ converges locally uniformly to $f$. Moreover,

\begin{align*}
\oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} f_n(z) \, dz
&= \oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} \iint_{\Bbb{C}} f(z-\mathrm{x})\varphi_n(\mathrm{x}) \, d^2\mathrm{x} dz \\
&= \iint_{\Bbb{C}} \bigg( \oint_{\partial B_r(z_0)} f(z-\mathrm{x}) \, dz \bigg)  \varphi_n(\mathrm{x}) \, d^2\mathrm{x} \\
&= \iint_{\Bbb{C}} \bigg( \oint_{\partial B_r(z_0-\mathrm{x})} f(z) \, dz \bigg)  \varphi_n(\mathrm{x}) \, d^2\mathrm{x} \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Therefore $(f_n)$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions by Step 1. Since $f$ is a locally uniform limit of holomorphic functions, $f$ is holomorphic as well. (Cauchy integration formula guarantees this.)

---

**Addendum.** Locally uniform convergence of $f_n$:

Let $\bar{B}(0, R)$ be any compact ball in $\Bbb{C}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Pick $\delta > 0$ and $N \in \Bbb{N}$ as follows:

- Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $\bar{B}(0, R+1)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(z) - f(w)| < \epsilon$ whenever $z, w \in \bar{B}(0, R+1)$ and $|z-w| < \delta$. May assume that $\delta < 1$.
- Since $\varphi$ is compactly supported, there exists $N > 0$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \varphi_n \subset B(0, \delta)$ for all $n \geq N$.

Now for $z \in \bar{B}(0, R)$ and for $n \geq N$,

\begin{align*}
| f_n(z) - f(z) |
&\leq \iint_{\Bbb{C}} |f(z-\mathrm{x}) - f(z)| |\varphi_n(\mathrm{x})| \, d^2\mathrm{x} \\
&= \iint_{B(0, \delta)} |f(z-\mathrm{x}) - f(z)| |\varphi_n(\mathrm{x})| \, d^2\mathrm{x} \\
&\leq \iint_{B(0, \delta)} \epsilon |\varphi_n(\mathrm{x})| \, d^2\mathrm{x} \\
&= C\epsilon,
\end{align*}

where $C = \iint_{\Bbb{C}}|\varphi| = \iint_{\Bbb{C}}|\varphi_n|$ is an absolute constant. This shows that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\bar{B}(0, R)$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to prove the sequence $f_n$ converges locally uniformly to $f$?

Comment: Why don't you prove that (for $z,z_0\in U$ simply connected) $g(z) = \int_{z_0}^z f(z) dz$ is holomorphic as suggested in the comment, so that by the Cauchy integral formula it is analytic and $f(z)$ too ?

Comment: @user1952009, How would you prove that your $g$ is independent of path of integration over, say, some nice family of paths? As far as I have seen, any proofs of Morera's theorem using antiderivative boil down to showing that the antiderivative $F$ they constructed satisfies $$F(z+h) - F(z) = \int_{z}^{z+h} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta$$ where the integral is performed over the line segment (or even a 'good' path) from $z$ to $z+h$. But I see no reasonably easy way to achieve this from the setting of OP's version.

Comment: You are right, my bad.

Comment: @user1952009, No offense, I actually thank you for your comment because I had completely forgotten how the Morera's theorem is proved in general and had to open my textbooks. It was a good review.